# How to copy / transer files from ubuntu terminal into a digital-ocean space

Tags: digital-ocean, scp

Can I scp files to digital ocean space from ubuntu terminal?

I setup a space in my digital ocean account, I can drag and drop files into the space, but I cant figure it out the way that I can copy files to the space from the command line.

Do I have to use droplets, but its a additional server right? I dont want a server. I just want a space to store some files.

Comment: You can use s3cmd 2.x to connect to your DO Space. DigitalOcean also have [documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/resources/s3cmd-usage/) for that as well.

Comment: Thankyou, I saw your comment when I was posting my answer. I'll add this to the answer as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool called `s3cmd` which used to upload files and folders to s3 buckets in amazon. You can use this for the same purpose. But for digitalocean you will need an updated version of `s3cmd` (version 2 or above)

There is a `digitalocean` documentation about setting up `s3cmd` you can check it out from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/resources/s3cmd-usage/) as well

I got s3cmd latest python tarball

`wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/s3tools/files/s3cmd/2.0.1/s3cmd-2.0.1.tar.gz`

extract it

`tar xzf s3cmd-2.0.1.tar.gz`

Now install it using below command with source files.

`cd s3cmd-2.0.1`

`sudo python setup.py install`

Now you will need to obtain the `access token` and the `secret key` from digital ocean `api`
You can find the procedure [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-digitalocean-space-and-api-key)

after getting the token and the key run

`s3cmd --configure`

provide your region, and the bucket url, etc. then after the configuration

simply run

`s3cmd ls` to find out the bucket url

then you can upload files by running

`s3cmd put file.txt BUCKETURL`

if you want to upload directories

`s3cmd put -r folderName bucketname`